# How to prevent upload on an input type="file" in my html5 page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a file input in a page, I do some resizing and croping and get base64 src so I don't need the uploaded files at all. How do I prevent the form from sending the files to my server ?

Comment: We must see some code to know what you're talking about, without teaching you bad coding practice.

Answer (score 4):

The [Form submission algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-algorithm) has this step:

> If the *submitted from [`submit()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-submit) method* flag is not set, then
>   [fire a simple event](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event) that bubbles and is cancelable named
>   `submit`, at *form*. If the event's default action is prevented (i.e.
>   if the event is canceled) then abort these steps.

Therefore, if you want to prevent the submission of the entire form, you can use a `submit` event listener which cancels the event:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent submission
});
```

If you only want to prevent sending the file input, you should make the [construct the form data set](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-the-form-data-set) algorithm to skip it. An easy way is removing its `name` attribute:

> If any of the following conditions are met, then skip these substeps
>   for this element:
>
> - The *field* element is not an [`input`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) element whose [`type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-type) attribute is in the [Image Button](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#image-button-state-(type=image)) state, and either
>     the *field* element does not have a [`name`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-name) attribute specified, or
>     its [`name`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-name) attribute's value is the empty string.

You can do that with JS:

```
form.elements.initialNameOfTheFileInput.name = '';
```

Comment: I already do that and submit my form using AJAX. I need the form to be submitted and all its data but I don't need the files. When I `print_r($_FILES)` on the server-side, I see that the files have been uploaded. How do I prevent this. Thank you

Comment: @MouradKejji So you want to send the form without the file? Remove the `name` attribute of the file input.

Comment: Perfect ! Post this as an answer so I can accept it as the answer for this question. Thanks !